# My Laptop (HP/Compaq 2510p) running ubuntu 10.04 LTS keeps losing the WLAN connection

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wicd

I am using Wicd and can successfully connect to my ADSL router (Thomson TG 787) using WPA PSK.
But with regular interval I lose the ability to connect to Internet. I can ping the GW and can actually ping servers on the Internet but not connect to them using HTTP (Tested with both Firefox and wget). I would suspect the router unless for the fact that the problem does not show up when running Windows XP on the same computer and also, when the problem arises, a simple disconnect/connect in Wicd solves the problem, which does not involve the router (Except for the DHCP request).

I have searched Ubuntu forums without luck, most problems described relate to specific network drivers or other problems. Does anyone have the same experience with Linux/Ubuntu and WLAN?

**UPDATE**

It seems to be related to the fact that when it doesnt work, multiple arp requests are sent to the router until the IP stack gives up and issues "network down". But when querying the arp table the routers IP/mac is already there so arp is uncesary.

Then the router regulary sends gratuitous arp's which is an indication that the WLAN goes up/down on regular basis. But still, wireless local lan access work and internet hosts can be pinged.

Comment: Can you still access HTTP resources on the local wireless network (such as your router configuration page)?

Comment: Yes, that is what makes it so strange. I can access hosts on my local network (ssh/http), as well as the router configuration page. But only ping internet hosts.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a router issue.  Your router probably is not supported by DD-WRT (I like that firmware).  I suggest getting a new DD-WRT compatible router (upgrade the firmware of course) and plug that into the other router.

I haven't had any problems with my Linksys WRT54GL, and I recommend it.  DD-WRT is pretty stable and I use it at home and at work.